# gksudo is not taking full focus - python, glade

Tags: 18.04, python, bug-reporting, glade

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.
I got this script in python, and its uses Glade as a gui.

Here is the main file:
https://github.com/stuk88/UbuntuClearMemoryCache/blob/master/main.py

So.
The code at fault here is:

```
runAsRoot("gksudo sysctl vm.drop_caches=1")
```

And I dont know why dksudu is not taking focus.
Switching windows with alt+` is not working either.

Comment: Note that gksudo to start graphical applications is deprecated. Use pkexec, but better, prefer not to run a graphical application as root at all: have it elevate to root privileges only while actually performing the specific actions that require root permissions.

Comment: Okay its the answer. Thank you

Comment: OK, I have written it out as an answer in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a terminal command with `gksudo`. That will start the process, but of course leave you no way of interacting with it. You probably rather want to launch a terminal application, in which that command is started.

Note that `gksudo`  to start graphical applications is deprecated. Use `pkexec`, but better, prefer not to run a graphical application as root at all: have it elevate to root privileges only while actually performing the specific actions that require root permissions.